# Probability: Indicators function and random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given $A,B,C$ three events of a sample space, with their indictaros functions, $I_A$, $I_B$ and $I_C$. Prove that the application defined by $$Z=(I_A-I_B)*(I_C-I_B)$$ is a random variable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$(\mathsf1_A-\mathsf1_B)(\mathsf1_C-\mathsf1_B)$ is also an indicator function.

Can you find out yourself of what set?

Indicator functions of measurable sets are random variables.

Comment: I have tried, I started by finding (1A - 1B) and also (1C - 1B), but I think the images of the functions are between -1 and 1, that's where I struggle. So, the multiplication of these two functions should mean that the image is between -1 and 1 too, and I don't think that's correct.

Comment: The product cannot take value $-1$. For this one factor should take value $+1$ and the other $-1$ which is inpossible. The first demand requires that $1_B$ takes value $0$ and the second requires that $1_B$ takes value $1$. So the product can only takes values $0$ and $1$.